# How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery:Error href is null

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I'm trying to get to the default home link(href) on my sharepoint site using jquery but i keep getting href is undefined.
I would like to change it to another URL
I have tried

```
alert($(".static selected menu-item")[0].href).text();



<div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks">
        <div class="s4-tn" id="zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4">
            <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
                <ul class="root static">
                    <li class="static selected">
                    <a accesskey="1" href="/sites/Home" class="static selected menu-item" style="height: 11px; margin-top: 0px;">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Home</span>
                    <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a>
                    </li>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: Why use the jQuery hammer here? Yes you can, but should you? Why not change your navigation settings so that the Home link is now point where you want it?

Comment: This type of customisation is prone to fall over with the next release of SharePoint when they want to upgrade.  Using a more supported mechanism will help make these kind of transitions easier and make it easier to support.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select an element with multiple classes. Try this instead:

alert($(".static.selected.menu-item")[0].href);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert($("ul.static>li.selected>a.menu-item")[0].href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead alert($('static selected menu-item')['prevObject'][0].URL);

EDIT: If this works, you could also use $('static selected menu-item').end()[0].URL removing the 'prevObject' to make it future-proof.